# Amazon REST API using OAuth

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth

I build a mobile website with a registration form. This registration form will be using API. Below is a part of documentation they've provided.

I don't have any idea where to start. But can I use PHP on this? Do you have any sources or steps on how to do it?

Company ABC = client

The client follow the Representational state transfer (REST) standard allowing resources
created, modified and pulled with a standard set of GET, POST, PUT, DELETE HTTP requests.
Communication with client follows the REST architecture constraints including being stateless & cacheable.

All requests are performed over SSL. All responses are returned as JSON objects.

**API Authentication**

Client's REST API utilizes the widely used Amazon standard for authentication. Authentication with the member service requires a signed string affixed to an Authentication header.

**Data required for signing a request**

● Date Formatted
as such: “Mon Jan 01 HH:MM:SS GMT 2013”
○ You also need to put this exact date string as the Date Header

● HTTP Method (
GET, POST, PUT, DELETE..)

● Body NULL
if HTTP Method is not POST or PUT. This is the data being sent to
the server.

● PATH the
path of the request after the host for example: /Members/01kjhkjh789abcdef01234567
○ The prefixed slash is required.
○ Trailing slashes will result in a failed authorization.

■ For purposes of this documentation the ID will be
kjhkh75hgkuyf56465r65465564

■ For purposes of this documentation the Secret will be
75456464674676746547fhgv2tcoygvhgvrUcTVD5GvYimli

**Client member**

Building the signed request

1. If there is a Body present, perform a MD5 operation on it.
2. Build the String to Sign:

   HTTP_METHOD + “\n” + BODY_MD5 + “\n” + DATE + “\n” + PATH

   Some Examples:

   a. “GET
   Mon Jan 01 HH:MM:SS GMT 2013
   /Members/0123456789abcdef01234567”

   b. “POST
   e9d263d07a1533984e80ef808bd4efff
   Mon Jan 01 HH:MM:SS GMT 2013
   /Members”

   c. “PUT
   96db961798e74718065e7a06d6d14110
   Mon Jan 01 HH:MM:SS GMT 2013
   /Members/012mnb3456789abcdebmbmnbf01234567“
3. Perform a hashhmac/
   sha1 hashing operation on the string you just built.
   a. The output of this should be binary/raw and not hexits.
4. Base64 Encode the hashed string.
5. Prefix the identifier to the Authorization scheme this
   is as follows:
   “CLIENT “ + API_ID + “:”

a. if your API_ID is “606e1a” your identifier will be
“CLIENT 606e1a:”
Examples

○ For the GET example above the output would be:

CLIENT lkmmklmlmlkm06e1a:l6PxyV73V226mklmklmkklB2XvaBsoWaE++Fo=

○ For the POST example above the output would be:

CLIENT klmlkmklmklmklm6e1a:FnSfYYxU+RTJlmlmlmlknSr/48yLYgk1eQ0=

○ For the PUT example above the output would be:

CLIENT lkmlkmklmlkm1a:ahByLYh9Wc3yhlmklmlm1F+N9ilkmlmkmLFA7B12w=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by using FF Poster (e.g.) to use / get an understanding of the APIs, and how u should be invoking them and consuming their responses.

In terms of technologies to invoke APIs.... what is ur current application stack? If php, [this](http://phphttpclient.com/) looks decent -  or google "php rest client". I have used Java rest clients, such as jersey and resteasy.

Comment: All I need is to POST the html registration form and check if the email is existing or not. Do you have an example source code to study?